# Create a CSV file with Java is impossible (Access Denied)

Tags: java, csv, office365, filenotfoundexception, .doc

I'm trying to create a CSV file in a Java program. No matter where the file is located, I've this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: <location> (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I have the same error for the .PDF and .DOC files.
I have no error with .TXT, .JSON ......

I have the administator rights.

I think it's Microsoft Office which protect .DOC and .CSV files.

Comment: "Access is denied" suggest you have permission issue. I would check which credential the Java application runas. Try some basic file reading from the temp directory just to eliminate code error or security issue.

Comment: Please post your code and the conrete file location. XY Problem?!....

Answer (score 1):

When you call new File your are supposed to give the file name, not only the directory you want to put your file in.

Try with something like

File file = new File("D:/Data/" + item.getFileName());

Comment: I would ask more question before post as "Answer" as others will mark you down :)

Comment: One possibility of error I just pointed out , if that helps him fine

Comment: File file = new File("D:/Data/" + item.getFileName());

This line works if the file is a .txt file or  .json file. But, if I try with a .csv file, it doesn't work. If I remove the extension, for example "result" instead of "result.csv", it works.

The problem is the extension .csv and I don't know how fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the `fileObj.getAbsolutePath();` to see if the file object is referring to the correct location/file.

If it is correct, then the problem is with access.

Remember, you may see the Access Denied error even if the file already exists and  is being used by another program.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider posting some code so that we can review the code blocks to identify a solution.